# Inserir quebra de linha em CSV a cada N caracteres

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código js que possui um var que recebe uma string e essa string precisa ser quebrada a cada n linhas de modo a não quebrar a largura máxima do conteúdo do csv. Além disso, é preciso que nenhuma palavra seja quebrada pela metade.

Qual seria a melhor solução para isso? Considerando o seguinte exemplo:

```
var n = 50;
var str = "Testando um algoritmo para quebrar esse texto a cada n caracteres sem haver quebra de palavras";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá amigo pesquisando na internet achei essa função:

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {

    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;

    if (!str) { return str; }

    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

     return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
}
```

Uso:

```
wordwrap('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 20, '<br/>\n');
```

Resultado:
The quick brown fox 
jumped over the lazy 
dog.

Funcao com concatenação do inicio e final:

```
  function wordwrap( str, width, brk) {

    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;

    if (!str) { return str; }

    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + '|\\S+?(\\s|$)';

    var array = str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') );

    var frase = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i]);

        frase += i + " " + array[i] + "\n";
    };

    return frase;
   }

alert(wordwrap('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 30));
```

Comment: Excelente, Matheus. Era de uma regex assim que precisava. Obrigado.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia inserir uma string no inicio de cada linha dessa? No final é facil a partir do parametro cut, mas não vi uma forma rápida de concatenar na frente.

Comment: Eu fiz uma modificação na funcao vou publicar logo abaixo, se puder me dar mais pontos por isso eu agradeço =D

Comment: Amigo, modifiquei a resposta acrescentando a função que eu modifiquei para concatenar no inicio e no final

Comment: Valeu, Matheus, pra isso acabei resolvendo aplicando algo assim:

<tag>' + wordwrap(frase, 130, '</tag>\n<tag>') + '</tag>';

Mas sua solução também fica ótimo. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a seguinte função que reproduz o funcionamento da [`wordwrap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) do PHP.

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {
 
    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;
 
    if (!str) { return str; }
 
    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');
 
    return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
 
}
```

Uso:

```js
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {
 
    brk = brk || '\n';
    width = width || 75;
    cut = cut || false;
 
    if (!str) { return str; }
 
    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');
 
    return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
 
}

var n = 50;
var str = "Testando um algoritmo para quebrar esse texto a cada n caracteres sem haver quebra de palavras";

var nova = wordwrap(str, n, "\n");
alert(nova);
```

[Fonte](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)